# Making text appear beneath submit box alerting user they haven't filled in the box

Tags: javascript, html

I'm about a week into learning HTML and JavaScript and I was wondering how I would make text appear beneath the input box for first and last name telling the user they have left it blank when left blank and submitted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
    function showInput() {
        document.getElementById('displayname').innerHTML = 
                    document.getElementById("fname").value + " " + document.getElementById("lname").value + " visited this on " + document.getElementById("date").value + " and said '" + document.getElementById("com") + "'";
    }   
</script>

<title>Great Pyramid of Giza</title>

</head>

<body>

<h2>Leave A Review!</h2>
<p>Have you been to this wonder of the world? If so, leave a review.</p>
<form>
  First Name:<br>
  <input type = "text" name="firstname" id="fname"><br>
  Last Name:<br>
  <input type = "text" name="lastname" id="lname"><br>
  Email Address:<br>
  <input type = "text" name="email"><br>
  Date of Visit:<br>
  <input type = "text" name="date" id="date"><br>
  Comment:<br>
  <input type = "text" name="comment" size="70" id="com"><br>
</form> 

<input type = "submit" value="Submit" onclick="showInput();">
<h2>Comments:</h2>
<p><span id='displayname'></span></p>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add the `required` attribute and the browser will do it automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a snippet pen for you, touched up some of your javascript, and added in the error messaging. There's a number of ways you could have accomplished this, but what I did in short was add an element below each input for which you want errors with an initial `display` value of `none`. On submit, I check to see if the first or last name values are empty strings, and if so set the error spans to `display: block`.  Check it out here:

```html
<html>

<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
    function showInput() {
      // Create references to DOM node text values, short circuit comment if not defined
      var comment = document.getElementById("date").value;
      var first = document.getElementById("fname").value;
      var last = document.getElementById("lname").value;
      var dateOfVisit = document.getElementById("date").value;
      var firstError = document.getElementById('firstNameError');
      var lastError = document.getElementById('lastNameError');
      // Grab reference to span element to output string
      var displayEl = document.getElementById('displayname');
      
      // Check falsiness of inputs
      // If falsey -> display error, else hide error
      if (!first) {
        firstError.setAttribute('style', 'display: block; color: red');
      } else {
        firstError.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
      }
      if (!last) {
        lastError.setAttribute('style', 'display: block; color: red');
      } else {
        lastError.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
      }
      // Set output string
      displayEl.innerHTML = 
        first + " " + last + " visited this on " + dateOfVisit + " and said '" + comment || 'not a thing...' + "'";
    }   
</script>

<title>Great Pyramid of Giza</title>

</head>

<body>

<h2>Leave A Review!</h2>
<p>Have you been to this wonder of the world? If so, leave a review.</p>
<form>
  First Name:<br>
  <input type = "text" name="firstname" id="fname"><br>
  <span style="display: none;" id="firstNameError">First name is required!</span>
  Last Name:<br>
  <input type = "text" name="lastname" id="lname"><br>
  <span style="display: none;" id="lastNameError">Last name is required!</span>
  Email Address:<br>
  <input type = "text" name="email"><br>
  Date of Visit:<br>
  <input type = "text" name="date" id="date"><br>
  Comment:<br>
  <input type = "text" name="comment" size="70" id="com"><br>
</form> 

<input type = "submit" value="Submit" onclick="showInput();">
<h2>Comments:</h2>
<p><span id='displayname'></span></p>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow! This really helps. Thank you!

Comment: I've added this to the whole of my code and it's not producing anything when I press submit. If I post it send you it all could you take a look please?

Comment: You could just add the updated snippet to your existing question and I can take a look. One thing to note, I did remove the ```doctype``` declaration at the top of the file bc codepen surfaced an error about it being unnecessary, so try adding that in. Also, did you just replace the function or replace everything

Comment: Sorry. I've just noticed the mistake I was making and now it works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a blank HTML element to contain the error message and then populate it or make it visible using JavaScript when your criteria is met (the field is left blank.)

**HTML:**

```
  First Name:<br>
  <div><input type="text" name="firstname" id="fname"></div>
  <div id="firstnameError"></div><br>
  Last Name:<br>
  <div><input type="text" name="lastname" id="lname"></div>
  <div id="lastnameError"></div><br>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function showInput() {
    var firstName = document.getElementById('fname').value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById('lname').value;
    if (!firstName) {
        document.getElementById('firstnameError').innerHTML = 'First Name is blank!';
    }
    if (!lastName) {
        document.getElementById('lastnameError').innerHTML = 'Last Name is blank!';
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to create a new function for this or shall this be included in the function that I already have?

Comment: You can wrap it up in your existing function or create separate error handling functions to better encapsulate your logic, especially if you want to do additional things when an input error occurs.